# Ruby on Rails: Signing out of devise, routing error, needs to submit twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have set up a logout button, but it takes me to the link, but doesn't sign me out. I shows

```
Routing Error

No route matches [DELETE] "/signout"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I have this

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

In my rake routing

```
 destroy_user_session GET    /signout(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
```

In my routes.rb

```
devise_for :user, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, :skip => [:registrations, :sessions] do 
  get 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

So the logout should just take me to `localhost:3000/signout` which it does, but thats where I get my routing error. However, when I enter in the URL the second time, while its in the routing error page, it final logs me out. Why does it not work the first time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifically telling your link (correctly) to use the DELETE method, but your route doesn't match that. Change:

```
get 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
```

To:

```
delete 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
```